# How is email verification by clicking a received link implemented?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I used parse-server, previously parse.com as my app's back-end. It was very simple that I never needed to worry about how the email verification was actually handled.

But I noticed that the verification link sent to user's email address opens up a plain html web page that has no JavaScript or anything communicating with the back-end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!-- This page is displayed whenever someone has successfully reset their password.
       Pro and Enterprise accounts may edit this page and tell Parse to use that custom
       version in their Parse app. See the App Settigns page for more information.
       This page will be called with the query param 'username'
   -->
  <head>
  <title>Email Verification</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    h1 {
      color: #0067AB;
      display: block;
      font: inherit;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 600;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      margin: 45px 0px 0px 45px;
      padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <h1>Successfully verified your email!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I wonder how the server was able to track that the link was indeed clicked and verified. How could they achieve this without sending some data back to the server?

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-app-email-settings/

Parse.com's blog doesn't explain the mechanism behind it. 
Please help my curious mind and thank you very much.

Comment: that's the response page you see (maybe even as a result of a re-direct), that's not the link you clicked (which would contain some sort of token that, when clicked is matched against 'pending' status tokens generated on the server side).

Comment: "*How could they achieve this without sending some data back to the server?*" - Clicking on a link already sends something to the server (an HTTP request).

Comment: That's true, can't believe I missed the HTTP request. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verification happens on the server. So you don't see any JavaScript within the page that is served to the client.

You can verify the email in a language installed on the server; PHP, JavaScript, Python etc.

So, say  a user submits his e-mail address to your app, you would send him a mail with a verification link.
The link has a parameter to identify the user again. In this case you can use a hashed value of the email address
e.g. *[www.mysite.com/email-verification-script/?user={a-hashed-value-of-the-mail}.](http://www.mysite.com/email-verification-script/?user=%7Ba-hashed-value-of-the-mail%7D.)*
The user clicks then on the link. The verification script evaluates if the parameter 'user' is valid. (Is this user in the system and can the user be verified?)
If so, the `email-verification-script` sets the user to verified and redirects to the success message page.
If the user cannot be found, show an error message.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! So will the server track the opening of the link, containing the hashed user email, by examining the HTTP request it received?

Comment: There are different ways of implementing it. One is to generate a one-way hash using the user's email, and then check it in the script. However, hashes can be cracked (many older ones are considered broken, such as md5), especially if an attacker is able to gather data using multiple email addresses, which is usually easy in most web applications. A more secure approach is to use secure random number generation to generate a unique code and store it in a database, then check it against the email.